# Python ImportError: No module named wx

Tags: python, importerror, wxwidgets

Im sorry to ask this question again. I have searched and found endles repeats of it both on stackoverflow and also on general google search. Unfortunatly I just cant get my system sorted.

I have the following:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
```

this folder contains the wx folder and also wx & wxPython folders which each contain the 
`_init_.py` files

When I import wx I get the error message `"no module named wx"`

What do I need to do in order to get Python to find the relevant files to allow me to "import wx" succesfully

Comment: "When I import wx I get the error message" -> where are you doing the import step (i.e. please provide more details) and are you sure that you're using Python2.7 when you do the import (I'm wondering if your default Python is another version)?

Comment: I have been running that code on the IDLE Python GUI `>>> import wx

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    import wx
ImportError: No module named wx`

Comment: Can you import other modules? Only wx fails ?. If this is the case, is there a wx.pth file in your site-packages folder ?

Comment: yes I can import all my other modules and packages and the wx.pth file is present in site-packages...Its just this sone Im having probles with..

Comment: Ops! what you describe is the correct setup... It should work... Did you installed from a binary from the official wxpython site? What was the name of if ? A different question, can you import wx from a python shell open in the windows console (instead of from idle).

Comment: thats interesting....YES I can import wx from the windows console ??? thats a bit strange.... what does that mean ?? why is it not working inside IDLE..

Comment: Joaquin... thanks so much that has fixed the problem... I closed IDLE and restarted it and it is now accepting the imprt wx statement....Yipee !!

Comment: You know? I have the least idea of why is now working and not before. Maybe you didnt restarted idle after installing wx ? um...

Comment: hello discussion from the distant past. same problem. restarting idle fixed it

Answer (score 55):

Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install python-wxtools
```

Comment: he uses windows, not ubuntu/debian

Comment: The fact OP has in the question `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode` means this answer will be rather less than useful.

Answer (score 30):

For Windows and MacOS, Simply install it with pip

```
pip install -U wxPython
```

Reference: [Official site](https://wxpython.org/pages/downloads/index.html)

Comment: for linux too, this is the best way

Comment: As per the site, for linux distro dependent, example: pip install -U \
    -f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-16.04 \
    wxPython

Answer (score 21):

Windows:

1. Go to `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\` find the folder `wx-<version>-msw` or similar
2. Move the `wx` from the above folder to `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\`

Comment: This worked for me after I installed wx from [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error today but I tried something and surprisingly it worked. In the site packages folder there will be a file named wx.pth. Open it using notepad and its contents would be like "wx-2.8-msw-unicode"

It is basically the name of the folder containing `wxpython`. Delete this using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and copy the name of the folder from the site packages and paste it here even if it is the same.

Sounds weird but maybe the original file contained a hidden character...

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem for a PyMOL plugin that required the wx module, though I installed wxpython by downloading its package from here ([Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#wxpython)) and installing it with the command:

```
pip install .\wxPython-3.0.2.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
```

For some reason it gave me that error, for which I uninstalled it with:

```
pip uninstall wxPython
```

and then I downloaded it from here ([wxPython 4.0.0a1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wxPython/4.0.0a1)) and reinstalled:

```
pip install .\wxPython-4.0.0a1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
```

The error at this point has not been presented anymore.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

```
pip install --user -U wxPython
```

Answer (score 3):

In fedora you can use following command to install wx

```
pip install -U \
  -f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-16.04 \
  wxPython
```

Answer (score 2):

I too face the same problem, I like to share which I was faced so it can be helpful for anyone. In my case I have installed both python2. 7 and python3, and tested the application in python3 after some analysis I used

> pip show wxpython-common

to find the location of wx which was in

> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

so i understood in my case wx will work only in python2.7 environment

Comment: Yes but that's because python 2.7 is default on your system, try pip3

Answer (score 1):

I'm on 64-bit Windows 7 and went to:

https://wxpython.org/

Then downloaded the exe for my system, installed it, and it worked for me.

Comment: FYI - this installation requires windows admin rights

Comment: Download link: https://wxpython.org/pages/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

Download the .whl file from this [link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

The name of the file is: 
    `wxPython‑3.0.2.0‑cp27‑none‑win32.whl` for Windows 32 bit and python 2.7 and
    `wxPython‑3.0.2.0‑cp27‑none‑win_amd64.whl` for Windows 64 bit and python 2.7.

Then in the command prompt: `pip install location-of-the-above-saved-file`

Answer (score 1):

Just open your terminal and run this command thats for windows users
`pip install -U wxPython`

for Ubuntu user you can use this

```
pip install -U \
-f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-16.04 \
wxPython
```

Answer (score 0):

You may check if you have the directory where are the packages of Python (in my machine, this dir is C:\Python27\lib\site-packages) in the Path variable on Windows. If Python's path environment variable does not have this directory, you will not find the packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have wx installed on windows you can use :

```
 pip install wx
```

Comment: This failed with compile errors for me, using Python 2.7.

Comment: If the pip installation fails, you should install the binary from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: This command worked for me::                                                                               
          pip install wxPython

Answer (score -1):

I restart the IDLE and works for me!

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you choose the right project intepreter in the compiler.  I used the Pycharm, and I encountered the same problem.  And it was solved by choose the right intepreter.
This[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJ9bTO5yYw0&feature=youtu.be) may help you.

Answer (score -3):

Generally, package names in the site-packages folder are intended to be imported using the exact name of the module or subfolder.

If my site-packages folder has a subfolder named "foobar", I would import that package by typing `import foobar`.

One solution might be to rename `site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode` to `site-packages\wx`.

Or you could add `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode` to your PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Comment: please, don't do that, the name is correct. If you installation has been done properly there should be a file wx.pth in site-packages pointing to that folder name.

Comment: Hi....I have checked the site-packages folder and I do have the wx.pth file present....and it contains the follwoing single line `wx-2.8-msw-unicode` any suggestions for sorting this would be really appreciated !