# no module wxPython

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am using windows 8.1, 64 bit with python 2.7, and trying to import wxPython, which I downloaded from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
I installed it using pip
I have a wx and wxpython libraries in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
but when I try to import wx or wxPython I get an error message:
ImportError: No module named wx
or
ImportError: No module named wxPython

what is the problem?

many many thanks to any answer

ariel

Comment: Try downloading it from the official site and see if that works: http://wxpython.org/download.php#msw

Comment: thank you. i did and it worked.. my program raised other problems. It seem that psychopy and windows 8 don't go well together. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As it appears there is an answer it this forum.   [Python ImportError: No module named wx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609666/python-importerror-no-module-named-wx)
module wx is inside wxPython, and it needs to be copy-paste to site-package. as wierd as it may sounds. it works