# ImportError: No module named wx in scrapy python 2.7.13?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

i tried to give import wx in scrapy python 2.7.13 but i'm getting "ImportError: No module named wx"? can anyone help please? Thanx in advance!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609666/python-importerror-no-module-named-wx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python ImportError: No module named wx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609666/python-importerror-no-module-named-wx)