# Python: installation of wx fails on Mac

Tags: python, macos, pip, wxpython, python-2.x

I am running a python2 package that uses `wx` on a MacBook.  I'm running python 2.7.10.  When I run the package:

```
con@company_computer:~/dir/pasta$ python run_pasta_gui.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_pasta_gui.py", line 27, in <module>
    import wx
ImportError: No module named wx
```

so I try to install wx following advice from [Python ImportError: No module named wx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609666/python-importerror-no-module-named-wx#29254923)

I try to install via pip as also suggested on https://wxpython.org/pages/downloads/index.html:

`pip install -U wxPython`

&

`sudo pip install wxPython`

&

`sudo -H pip install wxPython`

but all of these say that it's already installed:

```
Requirement already satisfied: wxPython in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (4.0.7.post2)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from wxPython) (6.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from wxPython) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.17; python_version <= "2.7" in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from wxPython) (1.14.2)
```

and yet I get the original error back when I try to run `run_pasta_gui.py`

I was able to get this done on my Ubuntu VM by `sudo apt-get install python-wxtools` but this obviously isn't available on a Mac.

Following [Unable to import a module that is definitely installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295680/unable-to-import-a-module-that-is-definitely-installed?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) I've tried `sudo chmod -R ugo+rX /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` but I'm still unable to access the `wx` package.

How can I get `wx` working for my python2 installation?

Comment: Are you sure you're running the script with the correct Python installation? Can you specify the installation explicitly? Are you not using virtual environments?

Comment: @AMC python is 2.7.10  How can I tell that pip is directly working with that version? there shouldn't be any other python versions locally.  I'm not using virtual environments

Comment: _there shouldn't be any other python versions locally._ That can't be the issue, then. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the install in venv, and I was able to import and list the module

`(venv) air:~ yo$ pip install wxPython
Collecting wxPython
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/17/b0/3a39e3fbea922e2f1bf2a48d5ed14d7eb1173ec8dbd3a1187f105ae06355/wxPython-4.0.7.post2-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (16.9MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 16.9MB 3.4MB/s 
Collecting pillow
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/6a/41719faa7421602a85941867059f53787ac40c85c8fe9e6bb48809e3246e/Pillow-6.2.2-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl (3.9MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 3.9MB 2.7MB/s 
Collecting numpy<1.17; python_version <= "2.7"
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/09/96/84cf406fe7d589f3dba9fc0f737e65985a3526c6d8c783f02d4b5a10825d/numpy-1.16.6-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (13.9MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 13.9MB 301kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: six in ./work/virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from wxPython) (1.13.0)
Installing collected packages: pillow, numpy, wxPython
Successfully installed numpy-1.16.6 pillow-6.2.2 wxPython-4.0.7.post2`

`Python 2.7.16 (default, Feb 29 2020, 01:55:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.29.20) (-macos10.15-objc- on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
import wx
print(dir())
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'wx']`

Comment: are you using virtualenv? https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/ look for virtualenv

Comment: virtualenv is not installed